# Windows 7x64 pro formatting of ST6000NM0024 6tb drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, gpt

I'm wondering if anyone is having success installing one of these drives into a Windows 7 Pro x64 system.  I'm able to:

- attach the drive
- see it in my BIOS
- boot Windows, bring up the Disk Management MMC Snap-in
- see all 6TB of space with a GPT setup in the Disk Management MMC Snap-in

When it asks to format the drive, it runs for an hour or so, and eventually I get the BSOD. The BSOD is there until the minidump is complete and then the system reboots.

After that I have to disconnect the drive to get Windows to boot again (not surprising, just annoying).  To boot with the drive installed, I typically will wire the drive up, boot Acronis from CD, and reinitialize with GPT within Acronis. Once I'm there, I can boot Windows with the drive installed.

The Drive is a 6TB Seagate ST6000NM0024 Constellation ES3 drive (SATA).

- I have a mini-crash dump which I would send if asked.
- I have upgraded the Intel AHCI drivers to the latest.

I'm only interested in using the drive for data so I don't care so much about being able to boot from the drive.  I obviously need to format the drive which is where I'm stuck now. I'd like to be able to use the full 6TB volume eventually (the issue with formatting makes me wonder whether normal operation will work even if I can get it to format).

Comment: I have several of these in my machine in an array

Comment: @KW9 When posting questions, just write. Please don't insert so many random breaks anywhere, and try to keep the message clear. I cleaned it up for you, and hope that you can get the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. First I tried to install the OS in a similar HDD - resulting in BSOD, Then Installed the OS in another HDD - the System was OK Initially, and then the problematic HDD just dissapears, without any warning. After restart I was able to see it again. My advice is to update your BIOS and if it doesn't work, return the HDD.

Cheers,
Dave